# Cannot return the boolean value from the "every" function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean

I'm assuming it's some rookie mistake, but I just can't get my head around it.

```
  _internshipVerification = e => {
    const array = Object.values(this.state.internship);
    return array.every(this._notEmpty);
  };

  _notEmpty = element => {
    return element !== "";
  };
```

I'm trying to check if all elements in the array aren't empty and I'm guessing it works, because if I do `console.log(array.every(this._notEmpty))`, I do get expected behavior. However I can neither assign nor return `boolean` from the `array.every(this._notEmpty)`. It only works when I use `console.log`.

This is JSX:

```
 <button type="submit" onClick={this._internshipVerification}>
   <i className="fas fa-check" /> Submit
 </button>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you're saying that `_internshipVerfiication` doesn't return a boolean? Because from the code you have here, it looks like it should

Comment: Exactly. It does not

Comment: Please show the code / JSX that calls/uses `_internshipVerification` - works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/gean78vq/

Comment: The docs for `Array.every` suggests that it _always_ returns a boolean: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: I did, nothing. When I try to console the result, it works fine, but not when I return it or assign it to a variable

Comment: Like I said, chances are you're using it wrong. We need to see the rest of the relevant code.

Comment: I edited with JSX

Comment: Ok, so what exactly do you expect to happen? Clicking the button calls a function that returns true or false, but the code doesn't *do* anything beyond that. If this is about form validation, you need to use `onSubmit` (in the <form>), then call `e.preventDefault()` if the check fails.

Comment: I guess you want to `if (!array.every(this._notEmpty)) e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Well this is just part of the code. The goal is to check whether all fields of the form are fulfilled and if so, proceed.

Comment: @Seinfeld thanks for all the further clarification that you've added. Could you provide some more detail on how you were able to verify that you're not getting a boolean from that function? It seems, from the jsx which you provided, that the function _will_ return a value, but that won't mean that it'll do anything after that

Comment: Ah it's ok. I made a mistake, since I was calling it on the submit button and I just wanted to use it for testing purposes and I only used onClick instead onSubmit event. It's mistake on JSX side. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, returning `false` from onClick here doesn't prevent form submission; see here: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ur532j68/